# How to check if a string is alphanumeric in VBScript?

Tags: validation, vbscript, alphanumeric

Is there a function like IsNumeric() in VBScript to check if a string contains only alphanumeric (a-zA-Z0-9) characters? Or can this only be determined by regular expressions?

Comment: No such builtin function, but you can implement your own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ^ feature (not in class) of RegExps to search for characters not in (a-zA-Z0-9):

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
>> For Each t In Array("aA0", "a.0")
>>     WScript.Echo t, CStr(r.Test(t))
>> Next
>>
aA0 False
a.0 True
```